# Received NA Error with Multivariable Regression in R Not Sure Why

Tags: r, regression, na

I'm working on a project for my Economics capstone with a very large data set. This is my first time ever programming and I had to merge multiple data sets, 16 in total, with anywhere between 30,000-130,000 observations. I did experience an issue merging the data sets since certain data sets contained more columns than others, but I was able to address it using "rbind.fill" Afterwards, I attempted to run a regression but I encountered an error. The error was

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Here is the original code for the regression

```
ols_reg_mortcur1 <- lm(MORTCUR ~ EST_ST + WEEK + TBIRTH_YEAR + EGENDER + RHISPANIC + 
  RRACE + EEDUC + MS + THHLD_NUMPER + THHLD_NUMKID + THHLD_NUMADLT + WRKLOSS + ANYWORK + 
  KINDWORK + RSNNOWRK + UNEMPPAY + INCOME + TENURE + MORTCONF, data = set_up_weeks15st)
```

I googled the error for some possible solutions; I found solutions like "na.omit", "na.exclude"' etc. I tried these solutions to aval. This leads me to think I didn't implement them correctly or perhaps something went wrong with the merge itself. While I was cleaning the data I set unknown or missing values, listed as -88 or -99 in the data sets, to NA since I had to create a summary stats table. I'll attach my R doc. I do apologize for the length of the attached code below I was sure if to just attach the sections leading up to the regression or include other lines.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple, minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sounds like your missing data code is not uniform, that is, different coding schemes for representing missing values were employed across the datasets you merged - which is very understandable since they are disparate datasets from different research groups.   I would open the merged dateset with Excel, then save as a "tab-delimited text" file whose filename extension is .txt.   Then open the myfilename.txt file with Notepad, and do a search and replace and replace NA with nothing (don't type anything for the replacement).   Save the file as Excel or .csv, then retry with R.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message,
`0 (non-NA) cases` the likely reason is that you have at least one NA in each of your rows. (Easy to check this by using `na.omit(set_up_weeks15st)`. This should return zero rows.)

In this case, setting `na.action` to `na.omit` or `na.exclude`  is not going to help.

Try to find columns with most NA's and remove them, or impute the missing values using an appropriate method.